message count obtained in outlook folder graph query is not equal to count of actual messages in folder
generally in graph we can obtain the high level details of a folder using folder query and next level details such as the data of emails were obtained using message query usually the high level data such as child folder, total email count and other details we be same as of the actual items present in that folder & the no of messages returned in response with the message query.
but, in come cases the Total message count of a folder obtained with the folder query doesn't match the actual number of messages obtained in the message query within a folder.
I really didn't guess the reason behind this, is there any possible hidden items or any other thing that isolates set of emails which is not included in any of the responses & not viable in outlook.
I'd like to share the response of one of my folder that falls within the above case I mentioned. the reference folder attached is discoveryholds under recoverable items which is not actually seen by users in outlook. but, I also see this same issue in deleted items of many of my mailboxes within my tenant.
below is the response obtained for the
request on folder details with  folder query
request on details of messages with in the folder with count based on

the above response is obtained from which seems to be correct while I manually counted it.
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/mailFolders/recoverableitemsdiscoveryholds/messages?$count=true

It would be helpful if I know the reason behind this. Thanks in advance.

The folder "recoverableitemsdiscoveryholds" is a system folder that is used by Exchange for discovery searches and holds. It is possible that there are hidden or deleted items in this folder that are not visible to users in Outlook, but are still included in the actual number of messages obtained from the message query.

Special folders such as recoverableitemsdiscoveryholds might include system-generated items, such as metadata or placeholder messages, that are counted in the folder’s total but not retrieved in standard message queries.

Initially for sample, I ran the same query as below:
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/mailFolders/


When I ran the query to get the individual folder messages, I got the same number:
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/mailFolders/Inbox/messages?$count=true


In your scenario, as you are querying  recoverableitemsdiscoveryholds  which is a system folder that is used by Exchange for discovery searches and holds,  hence it is possible that there are hidden or deleted items in this folder that are not visible in Outlook but are still included in the actual number of messages obtained from the message query.

Special folders such as recoverableitemsdiscoveryholds might include system-generated items, such as metadata or placeholder messages, that are counted in the folder’s total but not retrieved in standard message queries.
In Exchange, by default there are special folders that only Microsoft uses internally. They're hidden from everyone else, but you can still find out how many items are in them.
To confirm this, try to query any other folder to verify whether the value matches.

You can also try Get-MailboxStatistics command to check the message in the mail folder.

In case of recoverableitemsdiscoveryholds it may be, but I have also seen the same case in Deleted Items folder which is not a special folder and just contains the items deleted by the user and this made me think that this might be also be seen in normal outlook default folders such as Inbox, sent Items etc. which I haven't encountered it yet.

Did you face the same issue with inbox folder?

nope, but I think if it is possible for deleted items folder then it might be same for inbox.

Can you please check and confirm?

I have replaced the graph query reference attachment on discoveryholds with deleted items. I have around 25 mailboxes in my test tenant and more than 10 of the mailboxes contains deleted items under the mentioned case and some mailboxes also have recoverableitemsdiscoveryholds, recoverableitemsversions, recoverableitempurges under this case and no other folders has this issue in my tenant and this doesn't conclude no folders other than this contains this count mismatch which brought me here!

Yeah it happens with the recoverableitemsdiscoveryholds as it is system folder

I have also checked with "Get-MailboxFolderStatistics" in powershell which contains a prop named ItemsInFolder which result the same count as the count obtained in folderquery!

Is it showing 8 but 6 is correct?

But in my environment I am getting the same count for both the queries for deleteditems

In the Deleted Items folder, some items might be in a state of soft-deletion, meaning they are not fully processed for deletion but are still present in the folder count. Maybe its due to this

yes, exactly. 6 is right based on the no of actual message graph response & the visible items with in that folder.

It might be due to the above stated reason

regarding processing time - With recoverable items I agree that it might be. but, in case of deleted items let's skip the graph response the actual message that I see in deleted items is 6 & when I delete a message in my mailbox it is immediately moved to deleted items.

I know we cannot predict or conclude with the context I shared as it isn't enough. but, this is what I all know about this case. There could be some reason behind this. I'll share more info if I get to know & Let's see if someone had faced the same and additional details from them may help. Anyway thanks for ur time on this :)

@sriram Is the issue resolved?

not yet! remains mystery.
